# How to get the class from a button with embedded divs VUE 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm converting elements over from jQuery into Vue 3 JS.

I'm creating a component called "CardID" that will have person's initials.

In some cases it will be selectable, in others not. So, I'm passing that class when I'm using the component to determine if it is selectable or not.

If a user clicks on it and it has the class "is-selectable", a blue border will go around it. Clicks again, and it goes away.

In Vue3, I believe the only way I can get the className on the element is through using the event.target.

This works great if I click the grey area of the button. But if I click on the white circle or the letter, it won't work.

Any help will be appreciated. I know the same thing happens in vanilla JavaScript.

Using the component...

```
<CardID class="is-selectable" symbolText="K" />
```

The code:

```
<template>
    <button class="card" :class="{active: isActive}" @click="checkClass">
        <div class="card__circle">
          <div class="card__symbol">{{ symbolText }}</div>
        </div>
    </button>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "CardID",
    data: function () {
      return {
        isActive: false
      }
    },
    props: {
      symbolText: String,
    },
    methods: {
        checkClass(evt) {
            if(evt.target.className.includes("is-selectable")) {
              this.isActive = !this.isActive;
            }
        }
     }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  .active {
      border: 2px solid #1971D4;
      box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 4px #fff;
  }

  .card {
  position: relative;
  width: 160px;
  height: 115px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  background-color: #E7E7E8;
}

.card__circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card__symbol {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 20;
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  color: #1d242b;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using a css-class instead of a prop to determine if the component is selectable or not?
You could skip the check for a className and instead simply check if the prop is true/false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `this.$el.className` instead of `evt.target.className` :

```
<template>
    <button class="card" :class="{active: isActive}" @click="checkClass">
        <div class="card__circle">
          <div class="card__symbol">{{ symbolText }}</div>
        </div>
    </button>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "CardID",
    data: function () {
      return {
        isActive: false
      }
    },
    props: {
      symbolText: String,
    },
    methods: {
        checkClass(evt) {
            if(this.$el.className.includes("is-selectable")) {
              this.isActive = !this.isActive;
            }
        }
     }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Custom components can have custom props, so you should create a `selectable` prop in you `CardID` component and use that to check behaviour.
Something like:

```
<template>
    <button class="card" :class="{active: isActive}" @click="checkClass">
        <div class="card__circle">
          <div class="card__symbol">{{ symbolText }}</div>
        </div>
    </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "CardID",
    data: function () {
      return {
        isActive: false
      }
    },
    props: {
      selectable: Boolean,
      symbolText: String,
    },
    methods: {
        checkClass(evt) {
            if(this.selectable) {
              this.isActive = !this.isActive;
            }
        }
     }
}
</script>
```

And use your component like:

```
// non selectable card
<CardID :selectable="false" symbolText="K" />

// selectable card
<CardID :selectable="true" symbolText="K" />
```

PS: also note that you can set a `default` value for your props, which is usually useful for boolean properties

Comment: Just to add to this answer here's an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-3-vite-starter-forked-jkjj4?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue).
It works fine in switching your active class no matter where you click.